# Sending to new another activity in viewpager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onfling

I have developed an application using viewpager and my class extends fragmentactivity. The app works just fine except that I want to send the application to an activity after the last page of the view pager when the user "flings" the screen.is this possible? please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement the [ViewPager.OnPageChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html). Inside the onPageScrollStateChanged check if you are on the last page and then call whatever Activity you want.